# Java profiling with mission control - Where I can see the spend time of my own methods?

Tags: java, profiling, wildfly, jfr

I have a webApp with wildfly, jpa, ejb and jsf. Now I want to know how much time my methods takes? So I started mission control and started the flight Recorder.

In the Report of the Flight Recorder I can see the hot methods and an overview of packages with Time spent. But I want to know what has been called by my own methods and how much time the methods spend?

For example:

> mypackage.Myclass.

in myMethod -- spend 4 ms

Comment: The method profiler in JMC/JFR is based on sampling, and on having a low overhead, and very useful for finding bottlenecks in production, but less useful for time measurements of specific methods. If you want time measurements there are probably other profilers to use, like suggested below.   JMCcurrently doesn't have any data aggregation to display everything that was called from your method, but we have several requests to fix that.

Comment: @Klara was this ever implemented?

Comment: No, that hasn't been implemented yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JProfiler, in this app you can find timeline and how been called your methods.